# How do I make an alias for a column name?

Tags: r

This is something really cool I hadn't seen before. You can do the equivalent of `mutate`, `group by` and `summarize` with aggregate in one command.

```
aggregate(state.x77,
          list(Region = state.region,
               Cold = state.x77[,"Frost"] > 130), mean)
```

I want to replicate this in the formula format. I am almost there.

```
state <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
state$states <- rownames(state.x77)
state$region <- state.region
aggregate(Population ~ region + (state[,"Frost"] > 130), state, mean)
```

I want to give the new column a name. I tried `AS "Cold"` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transform`

```
aggregate(Population ~ region + Cold, transform(state, Cold = Frost > 130),   mean)
#        region  Cold Population
#1     Northeast FALSE  8802.8000
#2         South FALSE  4208.1250
#3 North Central FALSE  7233.8333
#4          West FALSE  4582.5714
#5     Northeast  TRUE  1360.5000
#6 North Central  TRUE  2372.1667
#7          West  TRUE   970.1667
```

Comment: That doesn't work because region and cold become different lengths.

Comment: @Cauder In the data.frame method, 'x' is the entire dataset exccept the grouping columns.  If you want that, then replace `Population` with `.`